# Results returned from view in SQL Server differ depending on whether "=" or "IN" used

Tags: sql-server, view

I have a view created in SQL Server 2008 that appears to be giving different results depending on whether I user "=" or "IN" when querying it.

For example, I can run:

```
SELECT * FROM UsersToMigrate WHERE u_s_p_no = 123
```

...and it returns no records.

However, if I run:

```
SELECT * FROM UsersToMigrate WHERE u_s_p_no in (123, 456)
```

...then it returns records for both values, as expected.

The view is based on 4 subqueries that are UNION ALL'd together. The first subquery uses the analytical function row_number():

```
Select  
    Replace(SPMF.FirstName,',',' ') [FirstName],
    Replace(SPMF.Surname,',',' ') [SurName],
    SPMF.sp_email [Email],
     UA.username,
    UA.DomainLogon [DomainLogon],
    Case    When SPMF.TeamLevel = 3 And CL.cw_type in (2,6,10,14) Then 'Adult Social Care - Practitioner'
            When SPMF.TeamLevel = 2 And CL.cw_type in (2,6,10,14) Then 'Adult Social Care - Team Manager'
            When SPMF.TeamLevel = 3 And CL.cw_type in (1,4,5,9,12,13) Then 'Children Social Care - Practitioner'
            When SPMF.TeamLevel = 2 And CL.cw_type in (1,4,5,9,12,13) Then 'Children Social Care - Team Manager'
            When CL.cw_type in (2,6,10,14) Then 'Adult Social Care - Practitioner'
            When CL.cw_type in (1,4,5,9,12,13) Then 'Children Social Care - Practitioner'
            Else 'Adult Social Care - Practitioner'
    End [Role],
    password [EncryptedPassword],
    CL.OwningBusinessUnit [BusinessUnit],
    Case When ISNULL(UA.Status,1) = 1 Then 0 Else 1 End [Disabled],
    null [Owner],
    UA.date_setup [CreatedOn],
    u_s_p_no,
    defaultRole,
    CL.cw_type [cw_type]
From    (select * from (
            select *, row_number() over (partition by u_s_p_no order by status) as rownum1
            from useraccess) as x
         where rownum1 = 1) UA
Inner   Join (select * from (
                 select *, row_number() over (partition by s_p_no order by s_p_no) as rownum2
                 from ServiceProviderMasterFile) as y
              where rownum2 = 1) SPMF
Left    Join sp_class CL WITH (NOLOCK) On CL.Category = spmf.sp_cat and CL.class = spmf.sp_class
Where   IsNull(UA.IncludeInExport,1) = 1
```

I'm just wondering if this analytical function might be something to do with the problem?

Has anyone experienced anything like this? Any ideas why it might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have sample data?

Comment: in the SQL -  select *, row_number() over (partition by s_p_no order by s_p_no) as rownum2
                 from ServiceProviderMasterFile)   if s_p_no is unique, then you are selecting all records because you are partitioning by the field. if s_p_no is not unique, then there is no sort to indicate which record from a set of records with the same s_p_no is the top record, so the record you will get could vary at any time.  That bit looks strange to me.  It is either potentially inefficient, or incorrect.

Comment: The order in (partition by u_s_p_no order by status) can vary if there are ties in 'status'. Try with an additional id field to make sure ties are always calculated the same i.e (partition by u_s_p_no order by status, ID), (partition by s_p_no order by s_p_no, ID)

Comment: partition by s_p_no order by s_p_no - this always breaks on s_p_no, so ordering by s_p_no within that doesn't make sense.  It's like saying give me all the records for the name SMITH, then saying 'order them by surname' - the second instruction can have no useful effect.

Comment: The UsersToMigrate view should only contain one record per u_s_p_no. The row_number() part was added to overcome an issue whereby, due to the UserAccess table holding more than one record for certain u_s_p_no values, certain u_s_p_no's were appearing more than once in UsersToMigrate.

Comment: Cato - yes, it doesn't actually matter which order they're in for this purpose - if there are more than one, then we just want one...it doesn't matter which one

Comment: if you have two records in SPMF with the same  u_s_p_no, which you have said later can be the case, then the SPMF.firstname could be from either record, and it could vary between running the query.  also it could possibly vary by you making some seemingly unrelated change such as changing = 1 to IN(1).  You haven't told us exactly what you are seeing though, just that it sometimes works differenrtly

Comment: the initial problem with the two queries - sorry that makes no sense to me, unless bothe records returned somehow have u_s_p_no = 456

Comment: Cato - see original question...if I use "SELECT * FROM UsersToMigrate WHERE u_s_p_no = 123" then it gives me no rows. If I use "SELECT * FROM UsersToMigrate WHERE u_s_p_no in (123, 456)" then it gives a row for 123 and a row for 456, as expected.

Comment: In the larger piece of SQL, is there an ON clause missing completely?  You have an INNER JOIN that has no ON clause I can see.

Comment: If you are actually concerned with accurate results you should get rid of that NOLOCK hint. It can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows. Not to mention a whole list of other challenges that hint brings to the table. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0):

what if you do

```
SELECT * FROM UsersToMigrate WHERE u_s_p_no in (123, 456);
SELECT * FROM UsersToMigrate WHERE u_s_p_no = 123;
SELECT * FROM UsersToMigrate WHERE u_s_p_no  = 456;
SELECT * FROM UsersToMigrate WHERE u_s_p_no  = 123 OR u_s_p_no  = 456;
```

(1) is logically the same as (4) - the records returned by (2) and (3) should match with (4) - otherwise is data being changed somewhere?

Is the problem you described initially really the problem?  Does it exist in that simple form?

What was the larger piece of SQL shown for, if the problem occurs in simpler SQL?

Why does the larger piece of SQL appear to have some stuff missing from it?  Is it the 'real' SQL?